# SOAP 1.2 Function ("GetReference") is not a valid method for this service

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm trying to make request to service.

Here's link to wsdl file [WSDL](http://zelsoft.ru/intourxml_v2/BookingService.asmx?WSDL)

Here's code

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://zelsoft.ru/intourxml_v2/BookingService.asmx?WSDL", array(
'soap_version'=> SOAP_1_2,
'exceptions' => 1, 
));

$xml = <<<XML
<GetReferenceRq>
    <Login>Zelsoft</Login>
    <Password>zel123</Password>
    <Countries>true</Countries>
    <Regions>true</Regions>
</GetReferenceRq>
XML;


$struct = new SoapVar($xml,XSD_ANYXML,"GetReferenceRq");

try{
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($client->__getFunctions());
    print_r($client->GetReference($struct));
    echo "</pre>";
} catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

But i get an error

```
Function ("GetReference") is not a valid method for this service

$client->__getFunctions()
```

indicates that method exists

Thanks for answers

UPDATED

I solved this problem by setting soap.wsdl_cache_enabled to 0, but get another problem

i'm sending request with such code

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://zelsoft.ru/intourxml_v2/BookingService.asmx?WSDL", array(
'soap_version'=> SOAP_1_2,
'exceptions' => 1, 
));

class GetReferenceRq{
    public $Login = 'Zelsoft';
    public $Password = 'zel123';
}

try{
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($client->GetReference(new GetReferenceRq()));
    echo "</pre>";
} catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

but getting response

```
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Zelsoft.InTourXML.BusinessLogic.Base.GetBaseRqParams(SqlConnection cnn, BaseRq rq)
   at Zelsoft.InTourXML.BusinessLogic.Base.Connect(BaseRq rq)
   at Zelsoft.InTourXML.BusinessLogic.Reference.GetReference(GetReferenceRq rq)
   at Zelsoft.InTourXML.BookingService.GetReference(GetReferenceRq rq)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Answer (score 1):

There does not appear to be a Login or Password field on the `GetReferenceRq` data type in the `WSDL`.  I will show you how I came to this conclusion, and perhaps it will give someone else some clues on how to troubleshoot `SOAP`.

From the `$client->__getFunctions()` output, you can see the API signature for GetReference:

```
array(38) {
  [0]=>
  string(59) "GetReferenceResponse GetReference(GetReference $parameters)"
```

This tells you that the method `GetReference()` takes one parameter called `$parameters`,  which needs to be of type `GetReference`.  You can find out what that data type looks like by doing `$client->__getTypes()`:

```
array(157) {
  [0]=>
  string(43) "struct GetReference {
 GetReferenceRq rq;
}"
  [1]=>
  string(569) "struct GetReferenceRq {
 boolean Countries;
 boolean Regions;
 boolean Cities;
 boolean Districts;
 boolean Meals;
 boolean Currencies;
 boolean HotelServices;
 boolean HotelCategories;
 boolean Hotels;
 boolean Genders;
 boolean RoomTypes;
 boolean RoomCategories;
 boolean AccommodationTypes;
 boolean BookingStatuses;
 boolean TransferPointTypes;
 boolean TransferPoints;
 boolean TransferTypes;
 boolean Attractions;
 boolean Languages;
 boolean HotelChains;
 boolean Flights;
 boolean TourTypes;
 boolean TourDirections;
 int CountryId;
 int CityId;
 int TypeId;
}"
```

So you need to create a class that will contain your GetReferenceRq.  Your code will need to look like:

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://zelsoft.ru/intourxml_v2/BookingService.asmx?WSDL", array(
'soap_version'=> SOAP_1_2,
'exceptions' => 1,
));

class GetReference {
    public $rq;
}

class GetReferenceRq{
    public $Login = 'Zelsoft';
    public $Password = 'zel123';
}

$parameters = new GetReference();
$parameters->rq = new GetReferenceRq();

try{
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($client->GetReference($parameters));
    echo "</pre>";
} catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

However you now have new error:  `object has no 'Countries' property`.  Indeed, there is no Login and Password fields in the `GetReferenceRq` type.  Instead you will have to add Countries, Regions, etc.

If the web service requires authentication, you will have to refer to the documentation to find out how it works.